# Rails 5 - has_one :through with :class_name doesn't provide associated record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a straight forward association between 3 different models:

```
class Claim < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :private_car, class_name: 'Car'
  has_one :company_car, class_name: 'Car'
  has_one :user, through: :private_car
end

class Car < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :claim
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cars
end
```

The corresponding tables then have the following foreign keys defined:

```
Claim => ['private_car_id','company_car_id']
Car => ['user_id','claim_id']
User => none
```

The console output is as follows:

```
2.3.1 :007 > Claim.first.private_car
  Case Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "cases".* FROM "claims" WHERE "claims"."deleted_at" IS NULL ORDER BY "claims"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Car Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "cars".* FROM "cars" WHERE "cars"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "cars"."claim_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["claim_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => nil 
2.3.1 :008 > Claim.first.private_car_id
  Claim Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "claims".* FROM "claims" WHERE "claims"."deleted_at" IS NULL ORDER BY "claims"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => 1
2.3.1 :009 > Claim.first.user
  Claim Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "claims".* FROM "claims" WHERE "claims"."deleted_at" IS NULL ORDER BY "claims"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "cars" ON "users"."id" = "cars"."user_id" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "cars"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "cars"."claim_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["claim_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => nil
```

Any idea why the association is broken?

Answer (score 0):

When you specify a `has_one` relationship with `class_name` (without specifying the `foreign_key`), rails by convention looks for the foreign key `class_name_id` on the model `class_name`.

So, `has_one :private_car, class_name: 'Car'` is looking for foreign_key `car_id` on the model `Car`, which is not what you want.

---

What you want is this

```
class Claim < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :private_car, class_name: 'Car', foreign_key: 'private_car_id'
  has_one :company_car, class_name: 'Car', foreign_key: 'company_car_id'

  has_one :user, through: :private_car
end
```

with foreign keys `private_car_id` and `company_car_id` defined on the model `Car`